# jQuery adding class from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, class, object

This is a json file containing seat information.

```
var jsondata = {
    "who": "RSNO",
    "what": "An American Festival",
    "when": "2013-02-08 19:30",
    "where": "User Hall - Main Auditorium",
    "seats": ["00000000000000000011111111111111000000000000000000", "0000000000000001111111111111111aaa0000000000000000", "00000000000000aa111111111111111aaaaa00000000000000", "00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000", "000000000aa00aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1100aa000000000", "00000001111001111111111111111111111100111100000000", "00000aaaaaa0011aaaaaaaaa11111111aaa1100aaaaaa00000", "00001111111001111111111111111111111100111111100000", "000aaaaaaa110011111111111111111111110011aaaaaaa000", "00111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111000", "00aaaaa1111110011111111111111111111001111aaaaaaa00", "11111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111110", "0aaaaaaaaaaaa001111111111111111111100aaaaaaaaaaaa0", "01111111111110011111111111111111110011111111111100", "00000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000", "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100", "01111111111111001111111111111111110011111111111110", "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100", "00a11111111111100111111111111111100111111111111a00", "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000", "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111110011111111111110000", "0000000111a111111001111a1111a110011111111110000000", "00000000111111110011111111111110011111111000000000", "00000000001111111001111111111110011111110000000000", "00000000000000111001111111111100111000000000000000"],
    "rows": ["DD", "CC", "BB", "AA", "Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V", "U", "T", "S", "R", "Q", "P", "N", "M", "L", "K", "J", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"],
    "seatPrice": ["                  00000000000000                  ", "               0000000000000000000                ", "              0000000000000000000000              ", "             0000000000000000000000000            ", "         00  000000000000000000000000  00         ", "       0000  00000000000000000000000  0000        ", "     000000  000000000000000000000000  000000     ", "    0000000  00000000000000000000000  0000000     ", "   000000000  0000000000000000000000  000000000   ", "  0000000000  000000000000000000000  0000000000   ", "  00000000000  00000000000000000000  00000000000  ", "000000000000  000000000000000000000  000000000000 ", " 000000000000  00000000000000000000  000000000000 ", " 000000000000  0000000000000000000  000000000000  ", "                000000000000000000                ", " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ", " 0000000000000  000000000000000000  0000000000000 ", " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ", "  0000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000  ", "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ", "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  0011111111100  0000000000000    ", "       0000000000  111111111111  0000000000       ", "        00000000  1111111111111  00000000         ", "          0000000  111111111111  0000000          ", "              000  00000000000  000               "],
    "priceLookup": [10, 20] 
};


$.getJSON('jsondata' , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(jsondata.seats, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        });
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
    });
    $("#plan").html(tbl_body);
});
```

The function at the end works fine in terms of using the seat layout, however, I need to add the information held in `seatPrice` as the class of the `td`s generated from the function. I've tried essentially copying the last function but for the `seatPrice` object and appending it to the table, but this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions as to how I would go about this?

Comment: If I'm right about what you're asking you need to use two seperate, but equal length, arrays in tandem. Use the vanilla method `for (i in jsondata.seats)` and complete the HTML using `jsondata.seats[i]` and `jsondata.seatPrice[i]`

Comment: How can the information in seatPrice be a class?  Even if you just assigned the string in there as a class, it would be invalid.

Comment: @JeffB B Nested if statements would be used to change what would be appended

ie

`if (i==" "){ //append "blank" to class// } `etc

Comment: Makes sense now.  I didn't see that you were indexing into the string as well.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code to begin.  Why do you need to `$.getJSON()` if you already have the data in `jsondata`?  If you are really getting this data from an AJAX call, that's fine, but you need to refer to `data` in the function, not `jsondata`, or rename the parameter to the anonymous function.

The first argument in the function passed to `$.each()` is the index of the array.  You can use that to grab the `seatPrice` of the same index:

```
$.each(jsondata.seats, function (j, d) {
    var tbl_row = "";
    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
        var seatPrice = jsondata.seatPrice[j][k];
        var seatPriceClass = '';
        if(seatPrice == "0") {
             seatPriceClass = "notawesome";  
        } else if(seatPrice == "1") {
             seatPriceClass = "awesome";   
        } else {
             seatPriceClass = "none";   
        }
        tbl_row += "<td class='"+seatPriceClass+"'>" + v + "</td>";
    });
    tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/pJhgK/

Comment: This works in my Fiddle, but for some reason not in my actual document, and it's not throwing any errors... Strange one, but I'll work with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're use of $.each() to loop is complicating the problem. As popnoodles said, you can use a vanilla for loop.

Is something like this what you're going for?

```
$.getJSON('jsondata' , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    var tbl_row = "";

    for (var i in data.seats){
        tbl_row += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
    }


    for (var i in data.seatPrice){
        tbl_row += '<td class="' + i + '">this is a td</td>';
    }

    tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";   

    $("#plan").html(tbl_body);
});
```

Comment: Except for you are adding two elements.  The OP wants one element using data from both `seats` and `seatPrice`.  Also, you are using `i` for your first index, and then using `v`.